# Set gfortran environment variables on Windows

Tags: gfortran

From the Windows 10 console, I type

```
set GFORTRAN_LIST_SEPARATOR=','
```

so that

```
echo %GFORTRAN_LIST_SEPARATOR%
```

gives

```
','
```

However, compiling and running a program

```
print*,10,20
end
```

gives output

```
10          20
```

There is no comma. How do I set environment variables such as GFORTRAN_LIST_SEPARATOR on Windows? On Unix, after setting a variable, I export the variable, but Windows does not have an export command.

Comment: What if you just use `set GFORTRAN_LIST_SEPARATOR=,` (ie., not quoted)?

Comment: That works, thanks.